# @PostConstruct Wrong deploy in GlassFish

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

- My project is based in Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE
- Before a use Tomcat, but last migration project has one problem with ClassLoader, then change Tomcat 8 for GlassFish 4.1!
- In project has one @Component("i18N")
- in my Object call *i18N* has one method
- But i'm to deploy in GlassFish the file **site-1.3.0.0.war**
- Has put a wrong error
- In other project has same problem, but i'm dont have time to solve this problem, at now i'm need solved this.

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app 
[site-1.3.0.0] : The lifecycle method [init] must not throw a checked exception. Related annotation information: annotation 
[@javax.annotation.PostConstruct()] on annotated element [public void com.sys.resolver.SysResourceBundleRead.init() throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException,java.lang.InstantiationException,java.io.IOException,org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.ELException] of type 
[METHOD]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

add the method class

**
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception{

}
**

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, a method with `@PostConstruct` must not throw checked Exceptions.

So remove `throws Exception` from your method and catch it in the method body:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

   try {
         // bla
   } catch (Exception x) {
        // do something
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411854/glassfish-4-scans-for-postconstruct-with-cdi-disabled)
I already made work around that worked in my case.

You can solve this issue first by adding a web.xml with metadata-complete="true". Next you will want to make sure your context are in the Web root Directory /WEB-INF/.

With this glassfish can load all @PostConstructSpring dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding the **metadata-complete="true"** in the web.xml like:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" metadata-complete="true">
```