# Glassfish 4 scans for @PostConstruct with CDI disabled

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

I'm doing and upgrade from `Glassfish 3.1.2.2` to `Glassfish 4.1` for a set of `Spring` applications. Since I use the `Spring` to handle `@Inject` annotations, I have disabled Glassfish' CDI using this command:

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.cdi-service.enable-implicit-cdi=false
```

Still, when I deploy one of my applications, I get the following error message:

```
The lifecycle method [something] must not throw a checked exception.
Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotation.PostConstruct()] 
on annotated element [public void com.something.MyClass.something() throws 
java.io.IOException] of type [METHOD]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

The class in question is an abstract class with no implementations in the application that I'm trying to deploy, it's just something that is on my classpath.

Why is Glassfish validating my `@PostConstruct` when I've disabled CDI? Why is Glassfish validating `@PostConstruct` on something that can not become a bean?
How can I prevent Glassfish from interferring with *anything* that I'm using `Spring` for?

Comment: What happens when you add a beans.xml file with the discovery mode set to 'none' ?

Comment: I'm trying that now, but from what I understand it's not enough to place it in the war, each jar needs it as well. Which is really something I would like to avoid, specially since it from what I understand is supposed to be equivalent to disabling CDI on the domain..

Comment: Worth an experiment to see if disabling it at the level of the top-level war is enough - I would think so. In any case I'd still find it more dependable to disable it at the application level rather than having to manually configure it per-server.

Comment: I dont have any applications that need it, and the per server config is actually per domain. With one application per domain it's a lot easier than having to introduce ~70 beans.xml files that don't really give me anything.. Top level war disable did not seem to work, trying disable on the module holding the class in question..

Comment: did you put the beans.xml in the WEB-INF folder?

Comment: I have put beans.xml in the WEB-INF-folder and the META-INF-folder of my war, as well as the META-INF-folder of the jar-file with the problematic file, neither works.

Comment: Okay... that would make me suspect there is a deeper problem here unrelated to CDI being enabled or not. But narrowing down what is then going to be the needle in the haystack

Comment: Might not be related to CDI at all. I'll try removing the checked exceptions from the method, and hope it's not actually called (just validated..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotation `@PostConstruct` is a general annotation used in any dependency injection mechanism. The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) explicitely states that, unless used within an interceptor, it must be put on a method, which has `void` return type and throws no checked exceptions.

It is weird that Spring allows checked exceptions on post-construct methods, as there is not way how to handle them. But as this requirement is only a validation and can be ignored, Spring probably ignores checked exceptions and Glassfish does not. There is possibly an unnecessary Glassfish feature, that it scans and validates all classes, even if not used in CDI or any other mechanism (EJB, ...)

The best is to **remove checked exceptions** to align the code with the documentation and make it portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue first by adding a web.xml with metadata-complete="true". Next you will want to make sure your context are in the Web root Directory /WEB-INF/.

With this glassfish can load all @PostConstructSpring dependencies.

More of a work around in my opinion.