# Getting Exception while deploying war file in Glassfish 4 or 5

Tags: java, glassfish, war

I'm getting exception while deploying war file in Glassfish server 4 and 5. However I didn't have any issues in Glassfish 3.

The exception is "The lifecycle method [finalizeConfig] must not throw a checked exception. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotatikn.Postconstruct()] on anoted element [public void org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.finalizeConfig() throws java.security.generalSecurityException, Java.io.IOException] of type [METHOD].

It seems like conflict between jetty http server and cfx transport.

I googled and found some solutions but nothing works.

Tried by removing transport Jettyhttp in cfx bundle.

Tried by upgrading cfx version.

So looking for some perfect solution.

Comment: If you are deploying to Glassfish, you shouldn't have the non-glassfish transports (such as Jetty) enabled and/or configured.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `@PostConstruct` annotation, it shouldn't be used with methods that throw checked exceptions. GF 4 and 5 validate this and won't allow deployment. Since the error is raised for a Jetty class which you can't fix,you should remove Jetty and all classes that validate this rule from your application completely. There's no way how to configure GF to ignore this.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35428512/784594 for more details.